# How to change edit mode(pop-up+inline) dynamically in kendo ui grid on click of button in grid?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using mvc4 application .On one of my page i am using kendo grid.I want to add two buttons for editing, one is used for editing in pop-up and other for inline editing.

I want to change the grid edit mode dynamically on click of button.

Can any one help me out ?

Comment: Updated answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27126654/869661

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two editing modes at a time.

As a work-around you can use the **InLine** editing + template column with a button inside which on click opens a window.

You can set the content of the window to be a [template](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview) and [bind](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/mvvm/index.html) it with the [dataItem](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#dataitem) for that row when the buttons is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change dynamically the edit mode for all rows in a `Grid` you can do:

`Button` and `Grid` definition:

```
<a href="#" id="popup" class="k-button">Popup</a>
<a href="#" id="inline" class="k-button">Inline</a>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

`Grid` initialization:

```
var grid = kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns: [
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" },
        { field: "field1", title: "Field1" },
        { field: "field2", title: "Field2" },
    ],
    editable  : "popup"
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

`Buttons` initialization:

```
$("#popup").on("click", function () {
    grid.options.editable = "popup";
});
$("#inline").on("click", function () {
    grid.options.editable = "inline";
});
```

When you click on either of these buttons, you select the edit mode as `inline` or `popup`.