# Two edit modes on a Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029405/how-to-change-edit-modepop-upinline-dynamically-in-kendo-ui-grid-on-click-of), I am wanting something simple that doesn't seem possible.  I have a Kendo grid.  I'd like a column on that grid to be a drop down box for quick and dirty updating of the data on the grid.  At the far right, I want an EDIT button that would popup a window for editing.

Currently the window and edit button are working fine, however I cannot find a way to make a column into a drop down box.  Seems like some sort of template should handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted was not possible per Kendo UI support. I did manage a work around though. The grid must be in `Server()` mode and not `Ajax()` mode in my case. So I setup the grid with a PopUp window editor.  Then I set up one of the columns as a DropDownList:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Status).Template(o =>
   Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("status_" + o.Id.ToString())
      .HtmlAttributes(new { data_orgvalue = statusList.IndexOf(statusList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == o.JobStatusCode)) })
      .DataTextField("Val")
      .DataValueField("Id")
      .BindTo(statusList)
      .SelectedIndex(statusList.IndexOf(statusList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == o.JobStatusCode)))
      .Events(e => e.Change("changeStatus"))
   );
```

Because the name was set using the Id, and because a change event exists, I added JavaScript that makes an Ajax call to update this field when the dropdown box is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `ForeignKey` column yet?  You can see a demo of it here: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/foreignkeycolumn.html

I'm not sure exactly how to have both edit modes, but I'm sure you could write some custom javascript to listen when the drop down value is changed.

Comment: Yes, I have tried one. My first problem is that I was unable to get it to work. The grid does in fact show the correct text, but when I click on the cell I only get a numeric up/down box where I am actually editing the Id value in that cell and not a drop down of possible text values.  My second issue is that this requires the grid mode to be InCell which breaks my popup window. It also requires the data source to be Ajax() rather than Server().