# Change edit mode dynamically in kendo grid on button click

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, inline-editing

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029405/how-to-change-edit-modepop-upinline-dynamically-in-kendo-ui-grid-on-click-of) Question I try to change edit mode dynamically in `kendo UI` grid and I succeed, But still have some problems. I want `kendo` grid let me to edit inline when I click on the cells and also let me to edit some template columns when I click on edit button. After I click on edit button `kendo` grid will refresh and edit mode will change to popup, But I have to click on edit button again to open edit window and this is the first problem, The second problem is edit window is close after I clicked on button again Immediately. I prepare some **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnmm1bqw/25/)** to make my question clear. How to keep edit window open?

Comment: Part of your problem is that grid.setOptions() basically completely reinits the grid(as it: completely tears it down and reinitializes it with the new set of options).  You want to leave the grid in in-cell editing and have the button pop-up a "regular" dialog that you control passing data to and receiving data back from...just like the second answer(from a former Telerik guy) in the question you linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14030222/4825632

Comment: @TheDreadPirateStephen Thanks for your comment but the problem is `grid.options.editable='popup'` does not work any more in new version of kendo UI. How to prevent refrsh kendo grid?

Comment: Use the second answer by Petur Subev as your starting point where *you* create and show your own window while leaving the grid in in-cell mode.